# Representing swing components in UML class diagrams

Tags: java, swing, uml, diagram

I have some questions regarding the representation of the gui objects in uml class diagrams.

For example if a have a class which extends the JFrame, then i will design the UML class diagram with the inheritance symbol, but in the JFrame, i do not need to write down all of it's class variables and methods, but only those whose my class will use right??

Second how will i represent that my class will use a specific layout manager? With the association symbol, i quess but i am not sure.

---

Say for example I have a package named `gr.mydomain.exampleproject`, and I have a class extending the JFrame.

Is the following approach correct or do I need to put the JFrame in a separate package (`javax.swing`)?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you must draw the inheritance symbol to the `JFrame` class, but leave the `JFrame` class empty, don't put any fields or methods in it. Everybody knows or can look at the API to see what `JFrame` contains. Besides, you would fill up the space with the multitude of methods present in `JFrame`.

Do it like this:

[image: UML screenshot]

As for layout managers: I believe the dependency relationship is the correct one in this situation. The association relationship would be correct if you would call methods on the layout manager's class. But you're probably just doing something like `frame.setLayout (new LayoutManagerClass ());` (a.k.a. just creating the object). In this case, it's a dependency relationship.

Comment: May I ask you which tool you used to create that class diagram?