# Is a JPanel represented as a class of its own in a Class Diagram?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I am developing a Java application that will have a JFrame with a tabbed pane inside it consisting of eight tabs. Each tab will have a JPanel in it.

If I am to draw a class diagram of this application, would the JPanels be represented as classes on their own under the JFrame's class or would I just include their attributes and behaviors in the JFrame's class?

Comment: No, each component/container is a class on its own, there isn't any relationship between them. However if you have a class that extends JFrame, then you would put that class as a child/subclass of JFrame.

You could do something like:

[Jcomponent <- JTabbedPane] 
[Jcomponent <- JPanel]

[Frame <- JFrame <- your class that extends JFrame]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, each component/container is a class on its own, there isn't any relationship between them. However if you have a class that extends JFrame, then you would put that class as a child/subclass of JFrame.

I drew this up as an example for you:

[image: class diagram]

Comment: You use an association to `Accessible`, but this must be a Realization.

Comment: @thomas Hi, could you please elaborate? I did this not to illustrate OP's exact model, but to demonstrate how classes and interfaces link to each other in theory. Thanks!

Comment: The connectors to `Accessible` need to be Realization connectors (dashed lines with open triangle as pointer symbol).

Comment: Once you upload a corrected diagram I'll take back the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can get any useful information from this post: [Representing swing components in UML class diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483029/representing-swing-components-in-uml-class-diagrams). 
If not, just post your comments so that I can research more and help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really drawing a class diagram, where one figure on the diagram represents one object/class, then of course you wouldn't put attributes of a JPanel within a JFrame figure, because that class does not have those attributes.

Class diagrams show relationships among classes, along with their attributes and sometimes their methods. A class diagram for a GUI application bears little resemblance to the GUI design of the application.

Comment: So basically I would have my JFrame class indicating it has the tabbed pane in it and underneath that class have the JPanel classes with their attributes and behaviours?

Comment: You would have a JFrame class indicating that it has an association with a TabbedPane class, which in turn would have associations with the JPanel classes that it uses.